# How can I set the wizard to go back if an error is found in a Custom Action

Tags: wix, windows-installer

If I find an issue from within my Custom Action checks (user chose a bad install directory in the WixUI_InstallDir dialog), after I let the user know of it (by using the _session.Message), can i somehow go back to that page in the wizard (the one that shows the install dir dialog)?

Right now I just return a ActionResult.Failure which is not ideal since he'll need to run the MSI all over again.

Update: I just noticed that when I return ActionResult.Failure, i'm still in the wizard with the "... wizard ended prematurely" message. The Finish button is enabled but the Back is not. Can I somehow change that so that the Back is also enabled? That would solve my problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't return a failure. Instead, set a MSI property (e.g. VALID_INSTALLDIR) to 1 or 0 based on your validation requirements. Then, condition the 'Next' button's SpawnDialog event on VALID_INSTALLDIR=1. This will keep the user from advancing to the next dialog until they choose a valid install path.